# 2d rigging vector to mesh

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, 2d

So I used Illustrator to create my character, converted to SVG, imported it to blender, converted it to mesh and organized it. Now I am trying to create a rig to animate and I can't. I've watched so many tutorials and still cant figure it out, and now in pose mode, the mesh is ruined every time as well as the bones are not unified when moving, I'm lost please help, lol.[image][image]
[image]
enter image description here

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Oh, ok, for sure, just one moment.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=70o7bAl7" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/70o7bAl7/)

Comment: it's not a good idea to create several armatures, unparent your meshes, merge all your armatures together with ctrl J, then select a mesh, for example the forearm, shift select the armature, switch to Pose mode, and press ctrl P > Bone

Comment: Im sorry, for some reason I just don't understand. How do I rig my character?

Comment: with the method I just gave you, only use one armature, not several, and parent each part of the body to each bone

Comment: I think I did what you said to do. I just feel like there has to be a way better way to do this. Also, I'm trying to use IK with this set up and its just not working. Idk, ...